# Style Transfer using tensorflow for model inception?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have written code which I am trying to make it work from many weeks, the problem is with the update on input not working.

```
     with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Run the noisy input image (initial generated image) through the    model. Use assign().
    ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
    init_fn(sess)
    sess.run(input_img.assign(inputo))

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    for i in range(num_iterations):

        generated_image,_ = sess.run([input_img,train_step])

        if i%20 == 0:
            Jt, Jc, Js = sess.run([Jolo, content_loss, style_losss])
```

Model Definition is done in this section, where I have defined shared Variable, and loaded inception v1 model from tf.slim

```
  with tf.variable_scope('input') as scope:
 input_img = tf.get_variable('in_img',shape=([1, img_height, img_width, 3]),dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())


 with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v1_arg_scope()):
 _, end_points = inception.inception_v1(input_img, num_classes=1001, is_training=False)

    # Create an operation that loads the pre-trained model from the checkpoint
  init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
os.path.join('home/n/models/inception_/', '/home/n/data/inception_v1.ckpt'),
slim.get_model_variables('InceptionV1')
    )
```

I am doing something wrong, and because of it update never happens.
Thank you

Comment: The default reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you have a look at my whole code?

Comment: This looks sketchy to me `sess.run(input_img.assign(inputo))`, you don't normally define tensor operations right in `sess.run`, every time I've seen it it's been a bug. Where is `inputo` defined? And can you define that outside of sess.run?  Also, you appear to be opening and closing your session before calling `sess.run`. Can you post your error message?

Comment: i am not getting error message, it just input image is not able to update, and even loss functions are not being minimized